# I want to change the format of my DataFrame in pandas. How can I do this?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

My current dataframe looks like this:

```
In [40]: result
Out[40]: 
  monthyear Facility       Date        Yield  Planned
0    Dec 15     CCM2 2015-12-01  2550.000000      0.0
1    Feb 16     CCM2 2016-02-01  4250.000000      0.0
2    Jan 16     CCM1 2016-01-01  1540.000000      0.0
3    Jan 16     CCM2 2016-01-01  6800.000000      0.0
4    Nov 15     CCM1 2015-11-01   921.458157    880.0
5    Nov 15     CCM2 2015-11-01  1750.310038   3000.0
6    Sep 15     CCM2 2015-09-01  5191.197065   8000.0
```

I need to change its format to the following:

```
         monthyear       Date         CCM1         CCM2      Planned
0           Dec 15 2015-12-01     0.000000  2550.000000          0.0
1           Feb 16 2016-02-01     0.000000  4250.000000          0.0
2           Jan 16 2016-01-01  1540.000000  6800.000000          0.0
3           Nov 15 2015-11-01   921.458157  1750.310038       3880.0
4           Sep 15 2015-09-01     0.000000  5191.197065       8000.0
```

How can I do this?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.   @Merlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `index` with aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['monthyear','Date','Planned'], 
                      columns='Facility', 
                      values='Yield',
                      fill_value=0).reset_index(level=2))
print (df1)

Facility              Planned         CCM1         CCM2
monthyear Date                                         
Dec 15    2015-12-01      0.0     0.000000  2550.000000
Feb 16    2016-02-01      0.0     0.000000  4250.000000
Jan 16    2016-01-01      0.0  1540.000000  6800.000000
Nov 15    2015-11-01    880.0   921.458157     0.000000
          2015-11-01   3000.0     0.000000  1750.310038
Sep 15    2015-09-01   8000.0     0.000000  5191.197065

print (df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())

Facility              Planned         CCM1         CCM2
monthyear Date                                         
Dec 15    2015-12-01      0.0     0.000000  2550.000000
Feb 16    2016-02-01      0.0     0.000000  4250.000000
Jan 16    2016-01-01      0.0  1540.000000  6800.000000
Nov 15    2015-11-01   3880.0   921.458157  1750.310038
Sep 15    2015-09-01   8000.0     0.000000  5191.197065
```

Last use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
  monthyear        Date  Planned         CCM1         CCM2
0    Dec 15  2015-12-01      0.0     0.000000  2550.000000
1    Feb 16  2016-02-01      0.0     0.000000  4250.000000
2    Jan 16  2016-01-01      0.0  1540.000000  6800.000000
3    Nov 15  2015-11-01   3880.0   921.458157  1750.310038
4    Sep 15  2015-09-01   8000.0     0.000000  5191.197065
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the quick solution... @jezrael

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day1